# Size of image texture determining size/proportion of plane?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, resolution

I do work where I render out essentially an image texture on a plane. Every time I change the image texture, I have to change the XY dimension resolution of the document, the plane scale and the camera and orthographic scale. It is all in direct relation to the size of the image texture.

Is there *any* way to automate this? I do this over and over, so recording and entering in these numbers gets very old.

Thanks.

Comment: You could write an small python script in blender which gets the image dimensions and sets the rest accordingly... a starting point could be: https://developer.blender.org/T20584

Comment: Maybe also add the tags python and scripting to this question

Comment: Have you seen the "Images as Planes" Add-on? It is built into Blender and you just have to enable it.